# Easiest way to check if multiple POST parameters are set?

Tags: php, for-loop, post, isset

Hi so I want to know the easiest way to check if multiple POST parameters are set. Instead of doing a long if check with multiple "isset($_POST['example'])" linked together by "&&", I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way of doing it.

What I ended up doing was making an array and looping over it:

```
  $params_needed = ["song_name", "artist_name", "song_release_date",
                "song_genre", "song_medium"];
```

I would then call the function below, passing in $params_needed to check if the parameter names above are set:

```
  function all_params_valid($params_needed) {
     foreach ($params_needed as $param) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$param])) {
           error("Missing the " . $param . " variable in POST request.");
           return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
  }


  if (all_params_valid($params_needed)) {
     $song_name = $_POST["song_name"];
     $artist_name = $_POST["artist_name"];
     $song_release_date = $_POST["song_release_date"];
     $song_genre = $_POST["song_genre"];
     $song_medium = $_POST["song_medium"];

     ...
  }
```

However when I do this, it gets stuck on the first index and says "Missing the song_name variable..." despite actually including it in the POST request, and I'm not sure why this is happening. The expected behavior would be for it to move on and tell me the next parameter "artist_name" is not set, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: var_dump() your $_POST - do your keys all exist with values?

Comment: `song_name` is either missing, has a typo, has a capital letter, or has extra spacing for some reason. `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST); echo '</pre>';` will reveal your issue.

Comment: Maybe your not sending a POST request? Check your `$_GET`.

Comment: If you want to return false after the first missing parameter found, there's nothing wrong with your function. The problem seems more related to not getting what you're expecting in $_POST, probably for one of the reasons in the previous comments.

Comment: [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) does take multiple parameters e.g. `isset($_POST["song_name"], $_POST["artist_name"], $_POST["song_release_date"], ...)` which is a bit cleaner

Comment: RIP you all were correct. POST is a pain to test, and there was an issue with postman, which is an application I use to test these kinds of things. Turns out I wasn't submitting my parameters as form data. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally like using `array_diff` for this issue.

[PHP array_diff documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

What you care about is your *expected input* is the same as the *given input*.

So you can use `array_diff` like this:

```
  $params_needed = ["song_name", "artist_name", "song_release_date",
                "song_genre", "song_medium"];
  $given_params = array_keys($_POST);

  $missing_params = array_diff($params_needed, $given_params);

  if(!empty($missing_params)) {
    // uh oh, someone didn't complete the form completely...
  }
```

Comment: I love this approach, this whole time I have always used array_map to achieve this. Great answer!

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but I think is should be array_diff($params_needed, $given_params); because it "returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: @JoshuaMaza fixed. Thanks for pointing that out! It's hard to remember all of these PHP quirks

Comment: Dylan Pierce - Change  if(!empty($missing_params) { to   if(!empty($missing_params)) { with an extra ) so it's valid syntax pretty please. Great solution that looks much better than tons of issets.

Answer (score 1):

How I approach this is by using array_map() so I can return all the values in the array whilst checking if it `isset()`

PHP 5.6 >

```
$args = array_map(function($key) {
    return isset($_POST[$key]) ? array($key => $_POST[$key]) : someErrorMethod($key);
}, ["song_name", "artist_name", "song_release_date", "song_genre", "song_medium"]);
```

PHP 7+

```
$args = array_map(function($key) {
    return array($key => $_POST[$key] ?? someErrorMethod($key));
}, ["song_name", "artist_name", "song_release_date", "song_genre", "song_medium"]);
```

Your error method could look something like this:

```
function someErrorMethod($key) { die("$key cannot be empty."); }
```

Inside of your `$args` variable, you will have an array of key => value. For example,

```
echo $args['song_name'];
```